# Most recent record from Elasticsearch Rails based on Multiple indices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I have two models in my Rails application: Share and Rent.

I'm starting to use ElasticSearch in my application and wanted a way to bring the models rent and share most recent.

I tried the following:

```
@response = Elasticsearch::Model.search query:     {
  "indices": {
    "indices": [
      "shares",
      "rents"
    ],
    "query": {
      "multi_match": {
        "query": "Apartament",
        "fields": [ "tipe"]
      }
    },
    "no_match_query": {
      "term": {
        "": ""
      }
    },

  }
}
```

But I do not know how to bring the most recent based on create_at field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows:

```
@response = Elasticsearch::Model.search query: {
      "indices": {
        "indices": ["shares","rents"],
        "query": {"match_all": {}
      }
    }, 
    size:10, 
    "sort": [
      {"created_at": {"order": "desc"}}
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch allows you to [sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html) according to a field, I'm not familiar with Rails but I guess you should try this:

```
@response = Elasticsearch::Model.search query:     {
  "indices": {
    "indices": [
      "shares",
      "rents"
    ],
    "sort": {
       "create_at": {
          "order": "desc"
       }
    },
    "query": {
      "multi_match": {
        "query": "Apartament",
        "fields": [ "tipe"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```